# Flexbox Uneven Spacing

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to get 50% (or really close) width on 2 divs in a flexbox row but it appears the content is making the width uneven.

I've a plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/RXor5bOR2s0hpa0jqjb8

```css
.input-group {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.input-group-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.input-group-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.input-group > label {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.input-group > label + * {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex: 1 0 100%;">
  <div class="input-group input-group-row">
    <label for="price">Purchase Price:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-row">
    <label for="dealDate">Date:</label><span>2016-02-25asdfasdf</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `flex: 1` on `.input-group` to make them equal `width`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.input-group {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-group input-group-row">
    <label for="price">Purchase Price:</label><span>$132.42</span>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-row">
    <label for="dealDate">Date:</label><span>2016-02-25</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

setting flex-basis to 50% fixes the issue:

```
.input-group { 
    flex: 1 0 50%;
    display: flex;
}
```

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PrFxvSdBBfsZ6IWHS4RD?p=preview)